# How to migrate a Postgres database to heroku using NodeJS?

Tags: postgresql, node.js, heroku

With Ruby, the migration only use a rake command, but in NodeJS, i'm not sure how i can do that. Any idea?

Comment: Is this what you are what you are looking for https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql ? But look out! **"Please note that all of these database plans incur non-trivial charges"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy your database up using [taps](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps)

Comment: Taps, I believe, use migrations. I just tried to push my database to heroku but the logs say that my relation (ie table) 'posts' does not exist. So I'm guessing the push command only updates data, not the structure of you db. Perhaps you could shell into the heroku database and recreate the tables there? But there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: https://github.com/visionmedia/node-migrate